# Query Not Returning Correct Results -- Sql Server Xquery

Tags: sql-server-2008, t-sql, xquery, xquery-sql

I have Sample Xml that looks something like this:

```
<tst:Root xmlns:tst="http://tempuri.org/some.xsd" SchemaVersion="0.2.1234.12345" RevNumber="1">
  <tst:stuff someID="1">This is <tst:comment>1st.</tst:comment> what I <tst:comment>2nd</tst:comment>just want to show</tst:stuff>
</tst:Root>
```

How can I just return "This is what I just want to show"?

Here is the tables and what I have tried.

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[XmlTable](
    [XmlId] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [XmlDoc] [xml] NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_XmlTable] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [XmlId] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY] TEXTIMAGE_ON [PRIMARY]

GO
SET IDENTITY_INSERT [dbo].[XmlTable] ON 

INSERT [dbo].[XmlTable] ([XmlId], [XmlDoc]) VALUES (1, N'<tst:Root xmlns:tst="http://tempuri.org/some.xsd" SchemaVersion="0.2.1234.12345" RevNumber="1"><tst:stuff someID="1">This is <tst:comment>1st.</tst:comment> what I <tst:comment>2nd</tst:comment>just want to show</tst:stuff></tst:Root>')
SET IDENTITY_INSERT [dbo].[XmlTable] OFF
```

and what I have tried:

This one only returns "This is" as expected.

```
--WITH XMLNAMESPACES (Default 'http://tempuri.org/some.xsd')
--SELECT     

--  a.value('text()[1]', 'nvarchar(100)') as SampleXml
--  From
--  XmlTable As x
--  Cross Apply XmlDoc.nodes('Root/stuff') a(a)
```

This one is returning everything:  "This is 1st. what I 2ndjust want to show"

```
WITH XMLNAMESPACES (Default 'http://tempuri.org/some.xsd')
SELECT     

    a.value('.', 'nvarchar(100)') as SampleXml
    From
    XmlTable As x
    Cross Apply XmlDoc.nodes('Root/stuff') a(a)
```

How can I exclude the comment nodes, but still get the correct results?

EDIT:

I want to return it like this:

[image]

Is there an easier way to do it than the following:

```
WITH XMLNAMESPACES (Default 'http://tempuri.org/some.xsd')
SELECT     

a.value('text()[1]', 'nvarchar(100)') + a.value('text()[2]', 'nvarchar(100)') + a.value('text()[3]', 'nvarchar(100)')  as SampleXml

From
XmlTable As x
Cross Apply XmlDoc.nodes('Root/stuff') a(a)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
 declare @xml xml;

 set @xml = convert(xml, 'your XML');

 with xmlnamespaces (Default 'http://tempuri.org/some.xsd')
 select @xml.query('//stuff/text()')
```

Assuming you have a table with an XML column, it would look like this:

```
 -- Set up the XML table to demonstrate
 declare @table table
 (
      ID int,
      xmlDoc  xml
 )

 -- insert your example XML
 insert into @table 
 Values (1, '<tst:Root xmlns:tst="http://tempuri.org/some.xsd" SchemaVersion="0.2.1234.12345" RevNumber="1"><tst:stuff someID="1">This is <tst:comment>1st.</tst:comment> what I <tst:comment>2nd</tst:comment>just want to show</tst:stuff></tst:Root>');

 -- Do the query
 with xmlnamespaces (Default 'http://tempuri.org/some.xsd')
 select ID, xmlDoc.query('//Root/stuff/text()') as SampleXml
 from @table
```

This is what my result looks like:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the response, I want it as a single row not 3!  I was able to get it with the updated query I posted, I was just wondering if there was a better way!  That doesnt seem to be the best way. Upvoted for the good response. Thanks again!

Comment: It can be simpler than you're making it.  Assuming your XML document is a field in a record, you don't need to use Cross Apply at all (unless you want to do other things you haven't mentioned).  See my updated answer for an example.